# How to group a collection to sum the properties of an object and generate a calculated field with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

how to group a collection by a specific field and generate a field calculated with the sum of the properties of an object with mongoDB, I don't know if it's possible to do what I'm trying to do but I would like to know.

I want to group by **duelId** field to add the score
Collection:

```
  {  "matches": [{
      "secondParticipant": {"name": "Maria","battlesWon": 2},
      "firstParticipant": {"name": "Fabio","battlesWon": 1},
      "duelId": "6c3e532d-3c0e-4438-8289-c86a4a51a102",
    },{
      "secondParticipant": {"name": "Fabio","battlesWon": 1 },
      "firstParticipant": {"name": "Maria","battlesWon": 1 },
      "duelId": "6c3e532d-3c0e-4438-8289-c86a4a51a102"
    },
    {
      "secondParticipant": {"name": "Luiz","battlesWon": 1},
      "firstParticipant": {"name": "Jose","battlesWon": 1},
      "duelId": "6c3e532d-3c0e-4438-8289-c86a4a51a666"
    }]}
```

expected:

```
 {[ [
      {
        "secondParticipant": {"name": "Maria","battlesWon": 2 },
        "firstParticipant": {"name": "Fabio","battlesWon": 1 },
        "duelId": "6c3e532d-3c0e-4438-8289-c86a4a51a102",
      },{
        "secondParticipant": {"name": "Fabio","battlesWon": 1},
        "firstParticipant": {"name": "Maria","battlesWon": 1},
        "duelId": "6c3e532d-3c0e-4438-8289-c86a4a51a102"
      },
      "score": { "Fabio": 2, "Maria": 3 } *// this field would be the sum of battlesWon after grouping*
    ], 
    [
      {
        "secondParticipant": {"name": "Luiz","battlesWon": 1},
        "firstParticipant": {"name": "Jose","battlesWon": 1},
        "duelId": "6c3e532d-3c0e-4438-8289-c86a4a51a666"
      },
      "score": { "Luiz": 1, "Jose": 1 } // *this field would be the sum of battlesWon after grouping*
    ]]}
```

Comment: matches is a collection name? or a field inside a document. also the expected is an array of arrays we cannot return exactly that from mongodb, we need to return documents not arrays

Comment: matches is a field within the document.

Comment: Double checking:  You expect to have 1 or more documents in the collection where the document has `matches` as a field and (clearly) `_id` as a field and possibly more?   Just want to ascertain the example is not restricted to only one document and that other documents in the collection can have the same `duelId` in the `matches` array field.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

1. `$unwind` the `matches` array
2. rename `firstParticipant` and `secondParticipant` into an array of k-v tuple for further processing
3. group by duel and name to sum up the score of each participant
4. group by duel to get the requested name-score tuple for each duel
5. use `$arrayToObject` to convert the k-v tuple array in step 2 back to the requested form.

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/I5HZ5RlhPJP) for your reference.

Comment: This is a good answer -- and it reveals why field names that denote ordinality ("first", "second") are better modeled as an array where `[0]` is the first and `[1]' is the second, etc.